# How can I fix this merge problem?

Tags: modeling

I'm doing this model where it required me to wrap around and I decided to merge at the end and you can clearly see where it was merged at the bottom left and I'm curious as to how I can fix this so it looks just as smooth as it does going around.

Picture:

[image]
https://gyazo.com/6af621669025c717b7f19ced3c7aaae8

Comment: You are gonna need to provide more information if you want any real answers. Might be a normal issue, try recalculating normals

Comment: Just tried it, doesn't do anything.

Comment: I thought editing the normals was used for if you create a face and it becomes inside out? But yeah when I tried it nothing happened.